# 1.2 million lines written every hour of the day in my system's log

Tags: logs, disk-usage, pop-os

**Something** is eating my disk space and I'm distinctly annoyed by it. This morning I woke up to the "No space remaining" notification, and I realized that it wasn't my torrenting what had beed steadily eating my disk space these last few weeks. I `du`'d my way around my filesystem, and I found out this:

```bsh
/var/log > du -hs * | sort -h 
...
480M    kern.log.2.gz
492M    syslog.2.gz
719M    kern.log.3.gz
737M    syslog.3.gz
1,2G    kern.log.4.gz
1,2G    syslog.4.gz
4,0G    journal
14G     kern.log
14G     syslog
19G     kern.log.1
19G     syslog.1
```

I inspected the files, and I was astonished about their contents:

```bsh
/var/log > tail -n 10000000 syslog.1 | uniq -cd -w9
 163183 Nov 13 15:52:09 raul-cloud kernel: [421137.114299] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1241786 Nov 13 16:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [421607.842156] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1226956 Nov 13 17:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [425207.640228] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1227458 Nov 13 18:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [428807.427407] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1226084 Nov 13 19:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [432407.225316] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1244380 Nov 13 20:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [436007.023373] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1229629 Nov 13 21:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [439606.810409] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1239934 Nov 13 22:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [443206.608482] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
1153889 Nov 13 23:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [446806.406534] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
  46701 Nov 14 00:00:00 raul-cloud kernel: [450406.193587] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
```

(`kern.log.1`, `syslog` and `kern.log` had similar lines)

What kind of eldritch monstrosity is waking up every hour of the day to yell 1.2 million freaking lines to 4 distinct files, and how can I slay the beast?!

Or, more seriously now, how do I find out what's logging these lines, how do I stop it, and what logs can I safely delete?

**Edit 1:**
Thanks for answering me. I know there are no eldritch creatures in Linux/Unix :D I'm a really new full-time user of the OS and everything (mostly) just worked until now, so I kinda panicked there

Anyways, here's the output of `lspci`:

```bsh
/ > sudo lspci -vv -s 00:01.3
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin ? routed to IRQ 27
    IOMMU group: 2
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=1f, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f7500000-f76fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag+ RBE+
        DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s (ok), Width x4 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug- Surprise-
            Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl+
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState+
        RootCap: CRSVisible+
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna+ CRSVisible+
        RootSta: PME ReqID 1800, PMEStatus+ PMEPending+
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix+, MaxEETLPPrefixes 1
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- LN System CLS Not Supported, TPHComp- ExtTPHComp- ARIFwd+
             AtomicOpsCap: Routing- 32bit+ 64bit+ 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled, ARIFwd-
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn- EgressBlck-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-8GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+ EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+ EqualizationPhase3+ LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        RootCmd: CERptEn+ NFERptEn+ FERptEn+
        RootSta: CERcvd- MultCERcvd- UERcvd- MultUERcvd-
             FirstFatal- NonFatalMsg- FatalMsg- IntMsg 0
        ErrorSrc: ERR_COR: 0000 ERR_FATAL/NONFATAL: 0000
    Capabilities: [270 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn- PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: LaneErr at lane: 0 1 2 3
    Capabilities: [2a0 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Capabilities: [370 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1- ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1-
        L1SubCtl2:
    Capabilities: [3c4 v1] Designated Vendor-Specific: Vendor=1022 ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=44 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

The thing is, 01.1, 01.3, 03.1 are `PCIe GPP Bridge` and 07.1 and 08.1 are `Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B`, but I don't really know how they differ or why the others are not throwing any errors. Is there any way to debug this further?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200906181852.GC13955@merlins.org/

Comment: "Interrupts" are the way hardware attracts the attention of the software. The message you're seeing indicates that a "native" interrupt was recieved that the system wasn't expecting. It's probably a hardware/cabling issue. Read `man lspci` and use `sudo lspci` to find more information about device `0000:00:01.3`. Repair/replace that device. Linux/Unix doesn't have eldritch monstrosities, logs are telling you something.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for you answer! I've been reading the output of `lspci` but the broken component is still unclear to me. I've updated the question with the output of `lspci`, do you think you can help me?

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks for the link! I do have an NVIDIA card (a GTX 750), but my system is a custom built 4 years old desktop computer, with an USB-C port that I've never used, and the interrupts are not being thrown by the graphics card (see post update)